# solr index issue on EC2

Tags: django, solr

I have an ec2 instance where I deployed a django 1.5 and solr project. When I run the following command: `python manage.py rebuild_index` to build the index initially, I keep getting the following:

```
WARNING: This will irreparably remove EVERYTHING from your search index.
Your choices after this are to restore from backups or rebuild via the `rebuild_index` command.
Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] y

Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
All documents removed.
Indexing 561 <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x2777550>.
TypeError: Element() keywords must be strings
```

I keep getting the above error everytime. I was able to deploy this locally on my Mac with no issue. Is there something else I need to do for Ubuntu EC2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try removing the Ubuntu supplied python-lxml if you have it installed and install using pip instead:

```
sudo dpkg --purge python-lxml
sudo pip install lxml
```

Then re-run rebuild_index

Comment: That's actually what I did. Forgot to update the question after solving it.